# Adding a data point or draw ellipse to MSChart at specified X-Value

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I have a chart with the Y-Axis's all integers and the X-Axis's are times in the format (HH:MM:SS OR ##:##:## ... Unsure if this is in DateTime format, it's read as a string). These X and Y-values are being read from a .csv file and change from file to file. Another file will have ONE of these X-Values and this is where I'd like add data point OR draw an ellipse. I only will have the X-Value (DateTime) being read and not the Y-Value.

This X-Value is an indicator of a Start Location of a Testing procedure that was done when recording the raw data.

The chart is also resize-able so I cannot just use the cursor location or the x and y value of the form itself since it'll change if the form is resized to full-screen, etc.

[image: Picture of chart and .csv file with the specified time]

Comment: _Unsure if this is in DateTime format, it's read as a string_ This will not work! You __need__ to add the x-values as DateTime if you want to use them for anything like placing your marker! Note that your datapoints will not even be spaced correctly (unless you have one point per date only)

Comment: The actual solution can be achieved in __many__ ways. Here are a few: Set its MarkerStyle -Color & -Size. Have a 2nd Series (type point) where you add the one point. Add an Annotation. Draw the circle in a Paintxxx event. - Imo setting a MarkerStyle is the simplest way.

Comment: If you want to draw or use a 2nd sereis and you won't have the correct y-value you will need to find it by searching the x-value in the points of series1. The other solutions will do the same but then work directly on the found point in series1

Comment: Yes; there is only one point per a specified time. Software is being used to record data per a second so whatever the Pressure (Y-axis) is at each second will be recorded and that's it. If I will have to convert every thing of type DateTime, then that will take awhile to revert to it.

Comment: _If I will have to convert every thing of type DateTime, then that will take awhile to revert to it._ So be it. Not really reasonable to avoid. Depending on how you add the points you may get away with this: get the points you search first, scan the values for its value while adding and when you hit is set the markerstyle etc.. - Not really recommended though.

Comment: Right. Fair enough. I will see what I can configure. I may have a workaround as well that I'm currently working with. Thanks.

Comment: Good. come back if you run into trouble..!